# JBoss: Custom start script

Tags: batch-file, jboss, cmd

I have a custom script I am running to build out a project in **Windows 7**.  The first command in the script starts the JBoss standalone server.  However, after it starts the server, the script stalls and doesn't execute all the way through (the rest of the script is essentially ignored).  How do I bypass this so that the rest of the script executes after the server starts?  I still want to start the server before anything else.

Below is the script with comments to explain each line.  I'm not sure if `#` designates a comment.

**project-build.cmd**

```
%EAP_HOME%\bin\standalone.bat # Start JBoss
cd %PROJECT_HOME% # Go to project webapp directory
grunt # Build out the project front-end
cd ..\..\.. # Switch to project root directory
mvn clean install jboss-as:deploy # Build WAR and deploy to JBoss
start chrome "http://localhost:8080/Project" # Open project home page in browser
```

Prepending `call` to the first line doesn't work either.  So, I think this is pretty JBoss specific.

P.S.: Is there a best practice when it comes to stopping the JBoss server?

Comment: Control still doesn't return to the custom script when I prepend `call` to the first line.

Comment: What about `start /b %EAP_HOME%\bin\standalone.bat`?

Comment: It works but everything seems to run in parallel.  The server starts at the same time as the maven build, and the last command doesn't even execute.

Comment: I figured it out... had to add a `call` command before `mvn` as well.